# Android - Going through the code but not POSTing?

Tags: android, httpurlconnection, android-networking

My complier goes through my code without errors but it does not post to the website?

I have taken online website http://posttestserver.com/data/ which allows me to post. Using cURL, I am able to post but however, it doesn't post when I run my code.

```
package cdlewis.pebbleaccelstream;

import android.os.AsyncTask;

import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;


public class PostMethod extends AsyncTask<URL, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void  doInBackground(URL... url) {


        try {

            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url[0].openConnection();
            System.out.println("Connection established");
            conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
            System.out.println("Read timeout");
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
            System.out.println("Connect timeout");
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            System.out.println("Post method");
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            System.out.println("set do input");
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            System.out.println("set do output");

            DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
            System.out.println("dataoutputstream");
            wr.writeBytes("Hello! ");
            System.out.println("hello");
            wr.flush();
            System.out.println("flush");
            wr.close();
            System.out.println("close");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error! ");
        }

    return null;

    }



}
```

Below is how I am calling my class:-

```
try {
    new PostMethod().execute(new URL("http://posttestserver.com/data/"));
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

It prints out all the `System.out.println()` in the code but doesn't print anything to the webpage

Comment: Use the Volley library to handle all of this, from Google. It works very well and is better than your AsyncTask. It also has priorities and caching (and much more).

Comment: But for the sake of sanity, I wish to know why it isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

You're only sending your request, but not checking what the response is.

```
int statusCode = conn.getResponseCode();

if (statusCode / 100 == 2) {

    // ok

    // can call conn.getInputStream() now
} else {

    // some error or a redirect

    // in case of error (4xx, 5xx) call conn.getErrorStream()
}
```

BTW you won't see much info in your `catch` clause.

Answer (score 0):

After System.out.println("close"); add 
conn.connect(); which is missed.